# How to set an AVAudio3DMixingRenderingAlgorithm for binaural mixing

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am making an iOS app and am trying to mix sounds into a binaural mix.
I have

```
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
var environmentMixer = AVAudioEnvironmentNode()

func initSound() {
    let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("sound", withExtension: "wav")!
    let f = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
    engine.attachNode(environmentMixer)
    let format =  AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: engine.outputNode.outputFormatForBus(0).sampleRate, channels: 2)
    engine.connect(environmentMixer, to: engine.outputNode, format: format)

    engine.attachNode(player)
    engine.connect(player, to: environmentMixer, format: f.processingFormat)

    //
    // somewhere here I guess I should set the rendering algorithm...
    //

    player.scheduleFile(f, atTime: nil, completionHandler: {print("done")})

    player.position = AVAudio3DPoint (x: 0.5, y: 0.25, z: 0)

    engine.prepare()
    do {
        try engine.start()
        player.play()
    } catch {}
}
```

but how do I set the environmentMixer to a different renderingAlgorithm?

This isn't it:

```
environmentMixer.renderingAlgorithm = AVAudio3DMixingRenderingAlgorithmHRTF
```

Xcode gives an error:
*"Use of unresolved identifier 'AVAudio3DMixingRenderingAlgorithmHRTF'"*

But what is?
(The above code snippet does play sound and places it somewhere in the stereo field... but it is clearly audible that it uses the default AVAudio3DMixingRenderingAlgorithmEqualPowerPanning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what that algorithm should sound like, but you can set it like this:

```
environmentMixer.renderingAlgorithm = .HRTF
```

Comment: (The algorithm takes into account how soundwaves move through the human head so it simulates 3d through just two speakers, headphones)